# why Debugfs entries not enabled?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a module that is cresting debugfs entries in /sys/kernel/debug/example .
But i didnt see those files in sysfs/kernel/example  directory.

I see this function which do the debugfs entry creations are called in late_initcall.
late_initcall(example_debug_init);
Will this late_initcall  affect the entry creation?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have not mount debugfs. Do it by:

```
mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug
```

For more information about using debugfs, read [debugfs.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/debugfs.txt?id=refs/tags/v3.13-rc5) in kernel Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Also you must enable the:

```
CONFIG_DEBUG_FS=y
```

configuration at build time, or else `mount` will fail.

Here is a minimal example: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/bb8f4eb79565c9771356c80e0964c8fefc163e11